# Google Font displays incorrectly only in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts, safari, google-fonts

I'm using this font: [Google Font - Faster One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Faster+One)

but it doesn't display correctly in **Chrome** (v59)

[image]

while on **Firefox** (and Safari), it shows correctly as on [Google Fonts website](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Faster+One)

[image]

What I also don't understand is that it still displays correctly on Google Fonts website using Chrome but not on my website.

*P.S. I'm aware that many similar questions have been asked before. But I still cannot find any clear solution for my case*

Comment: Are you importing the correct font weight?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the correct font weight. [Faster One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Faster+One) font on Google Fonts only has regular (400) weight (previously, in my CSS, I use 600)